# I am using hostinger hosting, and cannot get the website to run, in spite of having put the .html/.css files into the "public_html" recipient folder

Tags: web-hosting

thanks for any help attempts.

I am currently trying to run a website. [image]

I have put the dutch.html and english.html files into the folder.

[image]

But it had not worked, so I tried a second method I saw on another online tutorial thart is to put directly the files in their own "website" folder.

[image]

In the end I get this display (down below), that is a de default page [image]

While I had intended to display the following instead (that is the website): (down below) [image]

Comment: Why did you install WordPress if you don't want it to show up?  Are you expecting `dutch.html` to be the directory index page?  Did you add any configuration to make that happen?

Comment: Did you want to provide your domain name so we can probe it to see if we can make more educated guesses as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have put the files in the wrong place (ie public_html/Website) rather then just public_html/ - and/or you are not using index.php and this is preferred over default.php

Its worth noting that in a correctly configured Wordpress install (which you have), if a file is not found it feeds through Wordpress and shows the default page.   This may explain what is happening here.

What happens if you go to https://your.domain.name/default.php ?

Comment: From the screenshot, looks like `public_html/Website/dist/dist` (duplication of 'dist' folder) :) Overall, though, Stephen's comment above seems valid ... why create your own .html/.css files when you have Wordpress as a capable content management system for your page content?